# UITextView autoresize to adjust on a single line iOS Objective -C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitextview

I have a label called ratingstext and I want its contents to fit into a single line of text by means of adjusting height in case of multiple lines. How do I achieve that in iOS Objective -C.

**My label:**

[image]

as you can see the label shows 200/20 and is called ratingstext label. Actually the value is 200/200 but since I have used

```
    self.ratingsText.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 1;
```

The last 0 value gets chopped off due to fixed label width. How do I auto adjust width or height to fit in the content in a single line?

**My code is:**

```
self.ratingsText = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:self.frame];
self.ratingsText.editable = NO;
self.ratingsText.text = @"000/00";

self.ratingsText.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 1;

self.ratingsText.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:self.ratingSize weight: UIFontWeightRegular];
[self.ratingsText sizeToFit];
self.ratingsText.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
[self addSubview:self.ratingsText];
```

Comment: Did you try a `UILabel` instead of `UITextView` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a storyboard autoLayout will expand the frame to match the size of the text input. In the Attributes Inspector make the width textLabel "Relation" to "Less Than or Equal". I gave the text label in the storyboard 200/20 and in code set it to 200/200. Auto Layout took care of the rest. [image: Less Than or Equal]

Answer (score 0):

Use the below properties:

```
adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth
contentScaleFactor
minimumFontSize
```